# Text input in Shiny is not working when switching from MainPanel to Tabset views

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny App that takes a text input and shows it on the main panel (I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139348/shiny-printing-console-output-to-a-text-object-without-waiting-for-a-function-t?rq=1) answer to build it):

ui.r:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

    titlePanel("This is a test"),

    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
          textInput("text1", "Enter the text", ""),
          actionButton("goButton", "Go")
    ),

      mainPanel(
         h3(textOutput("text1", container = span))
            )
           )
          )
         )
```

server.r:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  cap <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    input$text1
  })

  output$text1 <- renderText({
    cap()
  })

})
```

It worked great until I decided to add a Tabset panel, and show the input on one of the tabs. I modified mainPanel() in ui.r as:

```
mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
              tabPanel("t1"), 
              tabPanel("t2", 
              tabPanel("t3"), h3(textOutput("text1", container = span)),
        )
      )
```

After this change, I am getting an error when launching an app:

```
ERROR: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the content within the tab within the call to `tabPanel`. Ex:

```
mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(
    type = "tabs",
    tabPanel("t1"), 
    tabPanel("t2"), 
    tabPanel("t3", h3(textOutput("text1", container = span)))
  )
)
```

Thus, server.R is unchanged from you question, and ui.R becomes:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("This is a test"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        textInput("text1", "Enter the text", ""),
        actionButton("goButton", "Go")
       ),
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          type = "tabs",
          tabPanel("t1"), 
          tabPanel("t2"), 
          tabPanel("t3", h3(textOutput("text1", container = span)))
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: it's an html tag

Comment: So sorry, extra comma in my answer. It should work now.

Comment: Interesting, I copied your code exactly and it works fine on my end. Try restarting R. You may have something in your environment that's the culprit. Let me know if that fixes it.