# Can I display rjags model loading text in real time in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, rjags

I have a shiny app that uses an action button to run a script that executes a JAGS model (through the package rjags) on the dataset that the app user uploads. Here is my simplified script:

```
# SHINY SCRIPT
ui <- fluidPage(
sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 fileInput("data_file", "Upload File", accept = ".xlsx"),
                 actionButton("run_script", "Run Script")

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$data_file, {
    file_path(input$data_file$datapath)
  })

observeEvent(input$run_script, {
        source("model.R")
}

# MODEL SCRIPT
runModel <- function(file_path) {
#...other code...

jags_output <- jags(dat, inits, params, "model.txt", nc, ni, nb, nt)

#...more code...
}

output <- runModel(file_path)
```

My problem is that this model can take a really long time to run (over an hour) and the published version of my app refuses to sit idle for that long without disconnecting no matter how I change the settings. To solve this I want to show the console text that's displayed in R while the model runs in real time so that (1) the screen is updating and doesn't time-out and (2) the user can actually see the model's progress. The console text looks like this and updates continuously:
[loading text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkzOs.png)

I've tried adding a clock to stop the timeout, but the clock pauses while the script is running. I've seen suggestions for sink() and system() but I don't understand base R well enough to incorporate these into my code. From here ([Possible to show console messages (written with `message`) in a shiny ui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474538/possible-to-show-console-messages-written-with-message-in-a-shiny-ui)) I found a promising option using withCallingHandlers:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 fileInput("data_file", "Upload File"),
                 actionButton("run_script", "Run Script")
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 verbatimTextOutput("model_progress")
                 )
               )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$data_file, {
    file_path(input$data_file$datapath)
  })

  observeEvent(input$run_script, {
    withCallingHandlers({
      shinyjs::html("progress", "")
      source("model.R")
    },
    message = function(m){
      shinyjs::html(id="progress", html = m$message, add=T)
    })
```

This gives me console messages in real time, but still doesn't show the model loading messages. It seems that the model messages are a different kind of message that aren't handled by withCallingHandlers. Any guidance about how to get that loading bar shown in shiny in real time?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139348/shiny-printing-console-output-to-a-text-object-without-waiting-for-a-function-t) helps?

Comment: @DaveArmstrong thanks, that got me to get the console messages in real time, but the model loading bar still doesn't show up. It seems R treats this as a different kind of message that isn't transferred as easily :/

Comment: Another option would be to use the `rjags` package.  Then, you could compile and initialize the model with `jags.model()`.  You could then call `update()` multiple times on a small number of iterations  each time and print a progress bar (e.g., [this](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/progress/))

Comment: @DaveArmstrong thanks, that is what I ended up doing. Printed "x% done" every 2% using a for statement and used sink() to redirect it to a text doc. Then pulled from the text doc to populate the textstream in the server function. For some reason it only worked when using system2() to run the script, not source().